# Logout Error: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This error has been driving me and a fellow dev insane.  We're building an app with Ruby/Rails jazz, and whenever I click to logout for a user session, I get this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Now I've ran rake routes a ton, and I get:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root        /                              home#index
                   about        /about(.:format)               home#about
```

Is there anything to be done here?  I've also followed the answers of a lot of the posts here on Stack Overflow to no avail.  Anything else I can test to try to fix this problem?

EDIT: Here is logout link code

```
<a href="/users/sign_out" class="header-links right-link" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a
```

Comment: when you click a link to logout, you actually send GET request, but your routes configured just to handle DELETE request, can you please show your logout link?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719229/devise-routing-error-no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out?rq=1 and a lot of others

Comment: How do you want me to show it?  It's on localhost

Comment: i mean the code in irb

Comment: added the code as i think you wanted it?

Comment: try <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete' %>

Comment: Is rails.js loaded? are you seeing any js error?

Answer (score 1):

Inspect you HTML and make sure rails.js is loaded, and there are no javascript errors. And if you are using jQuery, make sure that there is [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Note: My guess is you are running rails version < 3.1, So check if these two lines are present  in your layout

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Comment: This is a nice way to clean up their code, but if you actually try this you'll see that it generates exactly the same HTML as they've written by hand.  In particular `method: :delete` just generates `data-method="delete"`.

Answer (score 1):

does your routes have this under "devise_for"? :

```
get 'users/sign_out' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
```

And try this as link:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your routes.rb has,

```
devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

Sometimes my installs seem to miss this part `ActiveAdmin::Devise.config`and then I get this error.

I see it in the [gem's generator](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb) but sometimes it doesn't get added on my apps.